# Getting URI instead of File when using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-sharing

I am creating an app in which I let the user to share an audio file that is presen on the external storage.

I try to use this code but it is not working.

```
            //This is getting the absolute path of the parent folder where the
            //file is situated 
            File mFolder= new File(m_sdcard+m_confi);

            // This take us to folder where the file is situated
            File mAbFolder = new File(mFolder, "temp");

            // Taking the files in an array
            File[] mAllFiles= mAbFolder.listFiles();

            //Getting the URI 
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.androidpackagename.fileprovider", mImageFiles[1]);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Now when I am running this code, it shows me the share menu. But when I click on any item such as Gmail, it put the uri into the "TO" field.

And I also tried to share it on Whatsapp. When I select a user to share this, nothing happens and I get back to my app.

My manifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidpackagename">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.androidpackagename.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepath" />
    </provider>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My filepath xml is having

```
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="Android/data/com.androidpackagename/temp/" />
</paths>
```

Please help on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to use this code but it is not working.

That is not how you use `ACTION_SEND`. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND):

> Input: getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in EXTRA_STREAM.

So, replace:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(mContext.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
```

(though it would be much more efficient for you to just put in the MIME type directly in `setType()`, rather than using `getContentResolver().getType(contentUri)`, since hopefully you know what this file is and what its MIME type is)

Comment: Thanks for this answer and it worked but I still having some problems. The problem is my audio files are getting trimmed when I share them. The audio files are very small and they are audio recording, but in each sending the last one or two words are getting cropped.

Comment: @Raddix: `FileProvider` is not going to crop them. Perhaps the files themselves are shorter than you think.